# Powershell Logging within modules and dot sourced scripts

Tags: powershell, logging

I have a few functions stored in a .psm1 file that is used by several different ps1 scripts.  I created a logging function (shown below), which I use throughout these ps1 scripts.  Typically, I import the module within a script by simply calling something like:

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Module_Name.psm1
```

Then within the module, I have a write logger function:

```
Write-Logger -Message "Insert log message here." @logParams
```

This function is used throughout the main script and the module itself. The splatting parameter `@logParams` is defined in my main .ps1 file and is not explicitly passed to the module, I suppose the variables are implicitly within the module's scope upon being imported. What I have works, but I feel like it isn't a great practice. Would it be better practice to add a `param` block within my module to require `@logParams` to be explicitly passed from the main .ps1 script? Thanks!

```
function Write-Logger() {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Message,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$FileName = "Scheduled_IDX_Backup_Transcript",
        [switch]$Warning,
        [switch]$Error
    )
    # Creates new log directory if it does not exist
    if (-Not (Test-Path ($path))) {
        New-Item ($path) -type directory | Out-Null
    }

    if ($error) {
        $label = "Error"
    }
    elseif ($warning) {
        $label = "Warning"    
    }
    else {
        $label = "Normal"
    }

    # Mutex allows for writing to single log file from multiple runspaces
    $mutex = new-object System.Threading.Mutex $false,'MutexTest'
    [void]$mutex.WaitOne()
    Write-Host "$(Format-LogTimeStamp) $label`: $message"
    "$(Format-LogTimeStamp) $label`: $message" | Out-file "$path\$fileName.log" -encoding UTF8 -append
    [void]$mutex.ReleaseMutex()
}
```

Comment: You can utilize the `$PSCommandPath` automatic variable which will return the fullname property from the calling script.  I typically parse this for the basename and use that as the log's name.  This is only a problem when using the logging function within other modules since the log file's won't match.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks, that's a great suggestion for creating logs.  However, I guess what I am really trying to ask is what is the best way to incorporate logging within an imported script?  How do you pass the log path, file name, etc? Is it good practice to declare mandatory parameters at the beginning of a module for logging? Also, I edited the original question for clarity.

Comment: A common method in programming languages for logging is to have a logging object.  So if you're in PowerShell 5+, or you have C# experience, you can define a logger class object and utilize that where the object itself will contain those details as properties.

Comment: @mmartin712 I like your use of Mutex, I plan to incorporate that (i.e. steal that idea) into a logger class I use for generic logging (presently, I use a do/while/sleep routine). I use global variables and I hate to post it as an 'answer' but I think it maybe it may work for you (so I'm gonna do it anyway...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this code in ps1 that I dot source into scripts where I want to produce my own logs. The ps1 contains the `simpleLogger` class as well as the routine below that creates a global variable. The script can be dot sourced again and the global variable value passed to subsequently spawned jobs to maintain a single log file.

```
class simpleLogger
{
    [string]$source
    [string]$target
    [string]$action
    [datetime]$datetime
    hidden [string]$logFile = $global:simpleLog

    simpleLogger()
    {
        $this.datetime = Get-Date
    }

    simpleLogger( [string]$source, [string]$target, [string]$action )
    {
        $this.action = $action
        $this.source = $source
        $this.target = $target
        $this.datetime = Get-Date
    }

    static [simpleLogger] log( [string]$source, [string]$target, [string]$action )
    {
        $newLogger = [simpleLogger]::new( [string]$source, [string]$target, [string]$action )
        do {
            $done = $true
            try {
                $newLogger | export-csv -Path $global:simpleLog -Append -NoTypeInformation
            }
            catch {
                $done = $false
                start-sleep -milliseconds $(get-random -min 1000 -max 10000)
            }
        } until ( $done )
        return $newLogger
    }
}

if( -not $LogSession ){

    $global:logUser = $env:USERNAME
    $global:logDir = $env:TEMP + "\"
    $startLog = (get-date).tostring("MMddyyyyHHmmss")
    $global:LogSessionGuid = (New-Guid)
    $global:simpleLog = $script:logDir+$script:logUser+"-"+$LogSessionGuid+".log"
    [simpleLogger]::new() | export-csv -Path $script:simpleLog -NoTypeInformation
    $global:LogSession = [simpleLogger]::log( $script:logUser, $LogSessionGuid, 'Log init' )

}
```

Comment: Why create a new object every time you need to log something versus having a singular log object or something of that nature

Comment: So you're saying, like, create an object and then update the properties with each logged iteration? Not sure what you mean. I use this for long running tasks (like vSphere migrations, complicated app installs, OS deployments, etc.).
My class streams log output to a file and to the console for the local session, versus waiting for all tasks to complete to see the output . I can also retrieve output from jobs and add them to the same stream because the objects are identical. At some point I will try capturing job output via a thread safe variable, but right now I don't have good reason.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the `If` block of your example; didn't see the scroll bar.  I thought you were instantiating a new object every time you needed to log something and at that point, you're better off using a function

Comment: the entire code block above is in the dot sourced ps1 file. when it's imported into a session then the `if` statement creates a log session. once the class has been imported you log events `[simpleLogger]::log('source','target','action')` consecutive log entries will automatically be formatted to the same table width because they are the same type of object. while truncation occurs in the console, the written logs are in csv format and not truncated. I snub any other output and do if/else to keep the log stream whole. it works well when you want uniform console output from odd cmdlets